# ERROR: check constraint is violated by some row

Tags: postgresql

I have problem with my postgresql db.

I try adding a check constraint but it seems to be failing.

Gives me the error

```
"ERROR: check constraint is violated by some row"
```

The constraint is to avoid duplicates of same rows.
Looks like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.check_duplicates (character varying,bigint,numeric,numeric,bigint)  
RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS $$
        SELECT NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from db.users where name = $1 and id = $2 and weight = $3 and height = $4 and age = $5)
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql'
/
```

The function works fine.
When I try to make it a constraint with

```
ALTER TABLE
    "myDB"."db"."users" ADD CONSTRAINT users_ck1 CHECK (check_duplicates(name,id,weight,height,age))
```

It gives me the error.

Yet when I call it as a function with

```
select check_duplicates("Some name",1,1,1,1)
```

it works.

I thought maybe there were some null rows so I checked them with

```
select * from users where name is null or id is null or weight is null or height is null or age is null
```

It returned 0 rows.

I tried to check for duplicates with

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT *, count(*)
  OVER
    (PARTITION BY
      name,
      id,
      weight,
      height,
      age
    ) AS count
  FROM users) tableWithCount
  WHERE tableWithCount.count > 1;
```

It returned 0 rows.

I'm kind of lost right now.

How can I fix this?

I think the problem comes from somewhere else because when I try to create manually a unicity constraint that already exists (on id), it gives me the same error

```
--/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.check_dup_ids (bigint)  
RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS $$
        SELECT NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from users where id = $1)
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql'
/
```

I clearly don't get it.

Could help?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add so many different Postgres version - if you do use an unsupported version, add only a tag for **that** version.

Comment: Why don't you create a unique index instead? That's the most efficient way to ensure uniqueness

Comment: Because the data come from different databases. I have a unique_id on this table, but also have an "id" that is the id coming from the other databases.
Thus, two users can have the same id but be different, so I have to make sure they are not the same. (by comparing id (which is created by the creation date) and all other information)

Comment: You can still add a unique index for that

Comment: How does it work and what does it do exactly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the new constraint it is evaluated against each row existing in the table. Your function will return `false` for every row that already exists so you get the error.

The solution is to add a unique constraint like suggested above [comment by ahwnn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59863264/error-check-constraint-is-violated-by-some-row#comment105858005_59863264)

As an alternative you can use a trigger (before insert/update).

Just for an experiment to make your constraint work: Start with a function that always returns true, then add the constraint, then alter the function to behave as necessary.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer.

I cannot use a unique constraint because I'm getting this information from other databases. I made it simple for the question, but the real database has a unique id (which works fine) and a "object_id" coming from one or another database.
What I try to do is to make sure i don't add two same users coming from two different databases. (The user_id being a bigint created by the creation_date of the record).
So what I really need to do is make sure I don't insert values that already exist in the db for this information (while 2 user_id can be different users)

Comment: I will try to edit the function and work with the trigger and get back to you.

Comment: UPDATE : Editing the function after adding the constraint works perfectly fine, thank you very much!